# Register services with multiple lifetimes in unity

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I use Unity in an MVC5 project (.net461) for DI and I want to register a service with multiple lifetimes.

With the classic core DI I would use RegisterScoped and that's it. Whenever the service is resolved within an Http Request I would reuse the same instance for the duration of the request. If I want to fire a background task, that background task should open a service scope, and I would resolve a new instance for the service for the duration of that scope. No need to have different registrations for the service. In the first case, the scope is created by the runtime, and in the second it is manually created by the developer. In both cases, the service provider only knows that the service is scoped, it doesn't care about where and how the scope has opened.

With Unity the first case is solved with PerRequestLifetimeManager. The second case is solved with a HierarchicalLifetimeManager.

But how should I have a combination of the two?

Whenever a service is resolved within an HttpRequest (in a controller constructor for instace) it should use the PerRequestLifetimeManager and wherever it is resolved in a child container (within the constructor of another service that is instantiated in the child container) it should use HierarchicalLifetimeManager.

How can I register the service with both managers?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, I had to implement my own solution which is based on (but not using) [Unity.Mvc](https://github.com/unitycontainer/aspnet-mvc), [Unity.WebApi](https://github.com/devtrends/Unity.WebAPI) packages, and the [HierarchicalLifetimeManager](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.Lifetime.HierarchicalLifetimeManager.html).

None of the solutions I found online worked for my case. Most of them covered only the *per request* part, but not the per custom user scope part.

The key of the solution is not the lifetime manager but the dependency resolver. The lifetime manager for my requirements should always be `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` because that is what I truly need. A new container for each *scope*, which is covered by child containers and `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.

Using [Integrating ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection in MVC 4](https://scottdorman.blog/2016/03/17/integrating-asp-net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/) as an example on how to implement your own dependency resolver, I came up with the solution below.

What I had to do, is to make sure a new scope is created on the beginning of the Http Request, and Disposed at the end of the Http Request. This part is covered by implementing a simple `HttpModule`. This part is similar to the HttpModule used by the official Unity Per Request Lifetime implementation.

#### Per Http Request Module

This is the module implementation

```
internal class UnityPerHttpRequestModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private static IUnityContainer _rootContainer;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += (s, e) =>
               ((HttpApplication)s).Context.Items[typeof(UnityPerHttpRequestModule)]
                     = _rootContainer.CreateChildContainer();

            context.EndRequest += (s, e) =>
               (((HttpApplication)s).Context.Items[typeof(UnityPerHttpRequestModule)]
                       as IUnityContainer)?.Dispose();
        }

        public static void SetRootContainer(IUnityContainer rootContainer)
        {
            _rootContainer = rootContainer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rootContainer));
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
```

On Beginning the request we create a new child container and place it in the HttpRequest Items dictionary.

On Ending the request we retrieve the child container from the Items dictionary and dispose it.

The static method `SetRootContainer` should be called once at the startup of the application to pass in the initial root Unity container, the one that services are registered on.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UnityPerHttpRequestModule.SetRootContainer(UnityConfig.Container); // pass here the root container instance
            ...
        }
    }
```

We also need to register the module with owin.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.Startup), nameof(MyApp.Startup.InitScopedServicesModule))]

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static void InitScopedServicesModule()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerHttpRequestModule));
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

#### MVC Dependency Resolver

Now the http module is registered and we have a new scope created on each request. Now we need to instruct MVC and WebApi to use that scope. For this, we need to create the appropriate dependency resolvers. I created one dependency resolver for MVC and one for WebApi since they need to implement different interfaces (I could have implemented both in the same class though).

The dependency resolver for MVC is this:

```
internal class UnityMvcPerHttpRequestDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer rootContainer;

        internal UnityMvcPerHttpRequestDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer rootContainer)
        {
            this.rootContainer = rootContainer;
        }

        internal IUnityContainer Current => (HttpContext.Current?.Items[typeof(UnityPerHttpRequestModule)] as IUnityContainer) ?? this.rootContainer;

        public void Dispose() { }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return Current.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return Current.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

What the resolver does is that it checks for an HTTP Context and gets the unity container in the Context's item dictionary and uses this container to resolve the services. So effectively, if the service requested is registered with a Hierarchical Lifetime, a new instance of that service will be created within the child container (aka within the context of the request). Since the child container is disposed at the end of the request by the http module, any services instantiated in the child container are also disposed.

Things to notice here:

- The `IDependencyResolver` interface here is the `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver`. This is the interface expected by the MVC. The WebApi expects a difference IDependencyResolver (same name, different namespaces)
- Catching ResolutionFailedException. If you don't catch those exceptions, the application will crash.

Now that we have the MVC dependecy resolver, we need to instruct MVC to use this resolver.

```
    public static class UnityMvcActivator
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(UnityConfig.Container));

            //DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container));
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityMvcPerHttpRequestDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container));

            // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
            //Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
        }
    }
```

Things to notice here:

- Do not register the official UnityPerRequestHttpModule since we implement our own. ( I could probably use that module but my implementation would depend on the inner implementation of the official module and I don't want that, since it may change later)

#### Web Api Dependency Resolver

Simlilar to MVC dependency resolver, we need to implement one for the Web Api

```
internal class UnityWebApiPerHttpRequestDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer rootContainer;

        internal UnityWebApiPerHttpRequestDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer rootContainer)
        {
            this.rootContainer = rootContainer;
        }

        internal IUnityContainer Current => (HttpContext.Current?.Items[typeof(UnityPerHttpRequestModule)] as IUnityContainer) ?? this.rootContainer;

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope() => this;

        // Dispose, GetService and GetServices are the same as MVC dependency resolver
    }
```

Things to notice here:

- `IDependencyResolver` here is of type `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`. It is not the same as MVC's IDependencyResolver.
- This Dependency resolver interface implements one more method: `BeginScope`. **This is important here**. WebApi pipeline is different that MVC pipeline. WebApi engine, by default, calls `BeginScope` to open a new scope for each web api request, and uses *that* scope to resolve controllers and services. So, Web api has already a scoped mechanism. **BUT** we have already created a scope ourselves with our per request module and we want to use *that* scope. So what we have to do here is to not create a new scope again. It already exists. So calling `BeginScope` on our resolver should return the same resolver scope, thus we return `this`.

Now that we have created the WebApi resolver, we have to also register it to web api.

```
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.UnityWebApiActivator), nameof(MyApp.UnityWebApiActivator.Start))]

namespace MyApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with WebApi when it is hosted in ASP.NET.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Integrates Unity when the application starts.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use
            // a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
            // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container);
            var resolver = new UnityWebApiPerHttpRequestDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Registering services

Now that we have set up and registered all our Resolvers and modules, the last thing to do is to remember to register each scoped service with HierarchicalLifetimeManager. Since our scoped solution depends on child containers, registering our scoped services that way will suffice.

#### Conclusion

And with that, I managed to implement a working scoped DI solution with Unity. The example below did not work with the official Per Request Lifetime solution, but worked with my custom implementation.

```
class TestController{

   private readonly IMyScopedService service;
   private readonly IUnityContainer container;

   public TestController(IUnityContainer container, IMyScopedService service){
       this.service = service;
       this.container = container;
   }

   public ActionResult Post( ... ){

       var childContainer = this.container.CreateChildContainer();
       var scopedService = childContainer.GetService<IMyScopedService>()       

       HostingEnviroment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(() => {
             using(childContainer){
                   scopedService.DoWork();
             }
       });

   }
}
```

With the official PerRequestLifetimeManager solution, `this.service` and `scopedService` were the same instance. The scoped service was instantiated in the http context, then the same instance was fetched again from the child container (since it was registerd with PerRequestLifetimeManager and not HierarchicalLifetimeManager) and passed to the background Job. The background job outlives the http request. The instance is disposed when the Http requests ends, but it is still being used in the background job which probably runs in another thread. Concurrency issues (and more) arise. For instance you can't use the same instance of an EF DbContext in multiple threads.

With the custom implementation above, the example works. `scopedService` is a different instance since it is registered with a HierarchicalLifetimeManager. `this.services` is disposed when the http request ends but `scopedService` lives during the whole execution of the background Job.

What we effectively do is control the lifetime of the services by controlling the lifetime of child containers. And I have the impression that this is the solution for every scoped service scenario.

- Register all scoped services with HierarchicalLifetimeManager
- Control the lifetime of services by controlling the lifetime of the child containers.